# Firebase Notification contains both Title and Message

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-notifications

I am using [this](http://androidbash.com/firebase-push-notification-android/) tutorial to send `push notification` using `Firebase`

How can I show *`Title and Message`* both in Notification Bar`enter code here` (Still I am getting *`message`* as `*Title*` content in Notification Bar)…

As you can see in [this](https://i0.wp.com/androidbash.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/PushNotifyResult1.gif?resize=439%2C707) `screenshot` (due to this, I am `unable` to `deliver` complete `*message along with Title*` to users, because in Notification Bar title has limit `maximum 1 line`)

I am using `Advanced Rest Client (Messaging API)` to deliver Notification(s) like this:

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIza************adrTY

{ "data": {
    "image": "https://ibin.co/2t1lLdpfS06F.png",
    "message": "Firebase Push Message Using API"
    "AnotherActivity": "True"
  },
  "to" : "f25gYF3***********************HLI"
}
```

**Code**

```
/**
     * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
     */

    private void sendNotification(String messageBody, Bitmap image, String TrueOrFalse) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("AnotherActivity", TrueOrFalse);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setLargeIcon(image)/*Notification icon image*/
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.firebase_icon)
                .setContentTitle(messageBody)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                        .bigPicture(image))/*Notification with Image*/
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

`setContentTitle("title")` to set the title and of notification

`setContentText("text")` to set the text.

[A example from Android Developers:](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html)

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
    .setContentTitle("My notification")
    .setContentText("Hello World!");
```

In your case you will have to change your code to:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setLargeIcon(image)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.firebase_icon)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                        .bigPicture(image))/*Notification with Image*/
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setContentTitle(messageTitle) // here
                .setContentText(messageBody);  // and here
```

I recommend that you take some time studying `NotificationChannel` as well, if you wanna to support the new Android O notifications

[NotificationChannel example](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/notification-channels.html)

Comment: It means I have to use this line as well: String title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title"); just like in case of message I am using String message = remoteMessage.getData().get("message");

Comment: Yeap. `remoteMessage.getData().get("message")` goes to `setContentText` and `remoteMessage.getData().get("title")` goes to `setContentTitle` in your `NotificationCompat.Builder`